# Laravel 5.5 cannot make validator in a form Request class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, custom-validators

I want to check if a form input 'departement' is filled only if two 'villes' have the same name.

within controller this code wokds perfectly :

```
 $rules=[  'nom' => 'required', 'ville'=> 'required|exists:villes,nom'];
 $messages = [
      'depart.required' => 'Deux villes portent le même nom, preciser le 
 département'];
  $validator = Validator::make($request->All(), $rules,$messages);
  $validator->sometimes('depart_id', 'required|exists:departs,id', function 
  ($input) {
      return Ville::where('nom',$input->ville)->count()>1;
  });
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('admin/etab/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
```

I put the same  code in a Form Request  class:

```
public function rules()
{
  $rules=[  'nom' => 'required', 'ville'=> 'required|exists:villes,nom'];
  $messages = [
      'depart.required' => 'Deux villes portent le même nom, preciser le 
  département',
  ];
  $validator = Validator::make($this->All(), $rules,$messages);
  $validator->sometimes('depart_id', 'required|exists:departs,id', function 
  ($input) {
      return Ville::where('nom',$input->ville)->count()>1;
  });
  return $validator;
}
```

I get `"Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given,"` I think error message is inadequate but I cannot find why this way does not work

Thanks ......

Comment: Don't override the framework classes, just, don't. Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: The rules method in the FormRequest class should return an array, not a Validator object. That's the error you are seeing here.

Comment: @Robert I understand that rule is not the good place for my code but I can't find int documentation where in a FormRequest I should place my code...

Comment: @aprokryfos Sorry for bad explaining I do not override the framework Request class, I create a FormRequest class. (I edited post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the `FormRequest` class  in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php` and check what it does.

It contains these 2 method at the top:

```
/**
 * Get the validator instance for the request.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $factory = $this->container->make(ValidationFactory::class);

    if (method_exists($this, 'validator')) {
        $validator = $this->container->call([$this, 'validator'], compact('factory'));
    } else {
        $validator = $this->createDefaultValidator($factory);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'withValidator')) {
        $this->withValidator($validator);
    }

    return $validator;
}

/**
 * Create the default validator instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory  $factory
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function createDefaultValidator(ValidationFactory $factory)
{
    return $factory->make(
        $this->validationData(), $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']),
        $this->messages(), $this->attributes()
    );
}
```

So you can basically provide a `validator` method in your own FormRequest class to create a custom Validator object, that method will get the ValidatorFactory as param.

In your case you would not need to do this, because you just want to append the `sometimes` rule to a default validator. Looking at the code above, it checks for the existence of the `withValidator` method, if it exists, it is called:

```
    if (method_exists($this, 'withValidator')) {
        $this->withValidator($validator);
    }
```

You could create the FormRequest, make sure the `rules`, `messages` and `authorize` methods are properly used, e.g. rules and messages return arrays and authorize returns a bool.

Then create a `withValidator` method in which you attach the sometimes rule to the Validator.

```
/**
 * Do foo with Validator
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->sometimes('depart_id', 'required|exists:departs,id', function {
        return Ville::where('nom', $this->input('ville'))->count() > 1;
    });
}
```

This way `sometimes` is attached to your validator before the validation is performed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put all the validation logic in the rules method like that. Only the rule definitions go there. All you need is this:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'nom' => 'required', 
    'ville'=> 'required|exists:villes,nom',
  ];
}
```

Laravel will handle the validation from there on out. You don't need to manually create a `Validator` class when using `FormRequests`.

Customizing the message involves creating a `messages` method within the class like so:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'depart.required' => 'Deux villes portent le même nom, preciser le départemen'
    ];
}
```

**Update**

As for the `sometimes` rule, I'd suggest creating a Rule object and customizing how you need to check for 2 vills having the same name.

[Rule classes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: That's ok for checking if ville exists. But I want to check if departement exists only iif two vills have the same name. For that I need a sometmes rule....

Comment: Ok, but what I've posted is how the FormRequest class needs to be laid out. The way you have the validator instance and messages array within the `rules` method is wrong. Those need to be removed for the FormRequest class to work